# Delete a file which is x days old - batch

Tags: batch-file

First: I am new to batch. I got a batch file which should delete files in a folder which are 5 days or older. I use `FORFILES`:

```
FORFILES /p "C:\Users\rs\Desktop\testbatch" /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

This works quite fine, but: If I add a file to this folder and after 4 days I add another one to that folder, it delete both files after 5 days even if the second file is only 1 day old, because it's in the 5 days old folder.

Can someone give me a hint how I can say that the file has to be **min.** 5 days old before it deletes it?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: What you have described is not possible with that command line.  As a testing technique, use `cmd /c echo del @file` and you can test this in various folders with different files, to verify that it will only echo filenames that are 5 days or more old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

forfiles is detecting the directory as 5 days old, and executing then command over the directory. Change command to check if target is directory

```
FORFILES /p "C:\Users\rs\Desktop\testbatch" /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /c if not @isdir==TRUE del @file"
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I have to test it and this could take a few days because i have to wait >.< Thanks

Comment: you can change file date-created attribute with a simple powershell script to test this-> http://chrisjwarwick.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/modify-date-taken-values-on-photos-with-powershell-the-update-exifdatetaken-script-cmdlet-2/